# how to get random media id from media gallery

Tags: attachments, media-library

I tried to get random media id from wordpress media gallery using this:

```
$image_ids = get_posts( 
        array(
            'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
            'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
            'post_status'    => 'inherit', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        ) 
    );
    // based on the number of image_ids retrieved, generate a random number within bounds.
    $num_of_images = count($image_ids);
    $random_index = rand(0, $num_of_images);
    $random_image_id = $image_ids[$random_index];
    // now that we have a random_image_id, lets fetch the image itself.
    $media_id = get_post($random_image_id);
```

But it won't work properly.

Is there any way to get media id randonly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get_posts()` function to get random post, without additional php manipulation. 
Just change default orderby attribute to "rand" and set number of posts attribute equals to "1".

```
$image = get_posts( 
    array(
        'orderby'       => 'rand', //random order
        'numberposts' => 1, // numberposts, not posts_per_page
        'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
        'post_status'    => 'inherit' 

    ) 
);

//for testing purposes
echo $image[0]->ID;
```

Comment: can i use it on functions.php?

Comment: i need media id not the full url

Comment: "for testing purposes") This is an id - $image[0]->ID.

Comment: thanks @anton it works